# Issues with npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework, npm, proxy

I've been trying to setup ionic recently but I'm having trouble installing it with npm. I receive the following error when I enter `npm install -g @ionic/cli`:

```
λ npm install -g @ionic/cli
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/slice-ansi failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.20.35:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-20T08_03_25_334Z-debug.log
```

I've tried removing proxy settings and switching off my firewall but nothing worked. Also, some people online have said they have issues because they're using a company proxy or something like that but I'm using this at home and I'm not totally sure if I understand about the issue. I've been struggling with this for a few days now so any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Is this only the case when trying to install the Ionic cli or is this with every package?

Comment: I had the issue with react earlier but somehow I got it to work. Now it's back again unfortunately

Comment: What version of npm are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using 6.14.10

Comment: You might want to try using a proxy temporary https://npm.community/t/npm-g-install-etimedout-this-is-a-problem-related-to-network-connectivity/4278, some other people are encountering this issue

Comment: How do I actually do that? Little bit confused because I'm new to all of this so sorry about that

Comment: I would try to run with sudo first if you're running a linux based OS, or if you're windows open the CMD with Administrator privileges.

Comment: Yup, I've been running it with admin privileges